# Use "Configure<RequestLocalizationOptions>" and / or "UseRequestLocalization(options)"?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-localization, asp.net-core-7.0

I am using Request Localization in a NET Core 7 and Razor Pages application:

```
builder.Services.AddRazorPages();

builder.Services.Configure<RequestLocalizationOptions>(options => {
  options.DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture("pt");
  options.SupportedCultures = new List<CultureInfo> { new CultureInfo("en"), new CultureInfo("pt") };
  options.SupportedUICultures = new List<CultureInfo> { new CultureInfo("en"), new CultureInfo("pt") };
  options.RequestCultureProviders.Insert(0, new RouteDataRequestCultureProvider { 
    RouteDataStringKey = "culture",
    UIRouteDataStringKey = "culture",
    Options = options
  }); 
});

WebApplication application = builder.Build();

application.UseRouting();

application.MapRazorPages();

application.UseRequestLocalization();
```

The method `UseRequestLocalization` also accepts `RequestLocalizationOptions`.

Do I need to pass `RequestLocalizationOptions` to this method and also use:

```
builder.Services.Configure<RequestLocalizationOptions>
```

Or just one of those? And which one?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `AddRequestLocalization`/`UseRequestLocalization`, first one accepts action allowing to configure `RequestLocalizationOptions` via options pattern, second one setups [`RequestLocalizationMiddleware`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.localization.requestlocalizationmiddleware?view=aspnetcore-7.0) (enables automatic setting of the culture for HttpRequests based on information sent by the client in headers and logic provided by the application, consumes `IOptions<RequestLocalizationOptions>`).

Or you can pass the instance of `RequestLocalizationOptions` directly to [as done in the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/localization?view=aspnetcore-7.0#localization-middleware):

```cs
var supportedCultures = new[] { "en-US", "fr" };
var localizationOptions = new RequestLocalizationOptions().SetDefaultCulture(supportedCultures[0])
    .AddSupportedCultures(supportedCultures)
    .AddSupportedUICultures(supportedCultures);

app.UseRequestLocalization(localizationOptions);
```

The only difference how `IOptions<RequestLocalizationOptions>` created and handled - in first case they would be handled via DI.

Comment: So you are saying that using the Options pattern `builder.Services.Configure<RequestLocalizationOptions>(options => ...` together with `application.UseRequestLocalization();` without passing any options to it is equivalent to simply using `application.UseRequestLocalization(options);` but passing the options ... Is this correct?

Comment: @MiguelMoura more or less yes, there are small differences not directly related to the request localization itself.